# Not able to serialize java.util.HashMap object

Tags: java, serialization, input, hashmap

I am trying to write hashmap to file and read it back. Initially, my file is empty. so, when i try to read using readObject(), it throws EOFException. I caught it and proceed with normal execution. Then, I input details of a student. Insert the details in hashmap using rollnumber as key. Then, i write the hashmap to the file using writeObject(). I check the file and it had something written in it. 
    I close the program and execute it again.
    This time it should have read the hashmap that i had written. But, instead it clears the file and still throws EOFException.
    Help me.. how should i do it???

**Student.java**

```
package student;

public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    class Address implements java.io.Serializable{
        String house;
        String street;
        String city;
        String state;
        int pin;
        Address(String house,String street,String city,int pin,String state){
            this.house = new String(house);
            this.street = new String(street);
            this.city = new String(city);
            this.state = new String(state);
            this.pin = pin;
        }
    }
    private Address addr;
    private int rollnumber;
    private String courses[];

    public Student(String name,int age,String house,String street,String city,String state,int pin,int roll, String courses[]){
        this.name = new String(name);
        this.age = age;
        this.addr = new Address(house,street,city,pin,state);
        this.rollnumber = roll;
        this.courses = new String[4];
        System.arraycopy(courses, 0, this.courses, 0, 1);
        System.out.println("NEW STUDENT CREATED..");
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = rollnumber +" "+name+" "+age+"\n";
        return s;
    }

    int getRollNumber(){
        return rollnumber;
    }

}
```

I have made both classes Student and inner class Address serializable. Tell me if there is any trouble here.

**StudentRunner.java**

```
package student;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentRunner {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        String file = "student.txt";
        StudentProcessor sp = new StudentProcessor();
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

        HashMap<Integer, Student> hm= new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
        Student stud=null;
        try{
        hm = (HashMap<Integer, Student>)in.readObject();

                ///////// TROUBLE IN THE ABOVE LINE ///////////


        }catch(EOFException eof){
            System.out.println("sfdasfasfas");
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option=0;

        do{
            System.out.println("(1) Add User Details");
            System.out.println("(2) Display User Details");
            System.out.println("(3) Delete User Details");
            System.out.println("(4) Save User Details");
            System.out.println("(5) Exit");
            try{
                option = scanner.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                System.out.println("Error!!! provide valid option(1-5).");
                continue;
            }


        switch(option){
            case 1:
                try{

                    scanner.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter full name: ");
                    String name = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter age: ");
                    int age = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter rollnumber: ");
                    int rollnumber = scanner.nextInt();

                    scanner.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter Address:");
                    System.out.println("  Enter house number ");
                    String house_num = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("  Enter street: ");
                    String street = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("  Enter city: ");
                    String city = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("  Enter state: ");
                    String state = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("  Enter pin: ");
                    int pin = scanner.nextInt();

                    String courses[] = new String[4];
                    System.out.println("Enter four courses(A-F)");
                    System.out.println("  Enter first course: ");
                    courses[0] = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("  Enter second course: ");
                    courses[1] = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("  Enter third course: ");
                    courses[2] = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("  Enter fourth course: ");
                    courses[3] = scanner.next();

                    boolean flag = Validator.validateStudent(name, age, rollnumber, house_num, street, city, 
                                                             state, pin, courses);

                    stud= new Student(name,age,house_num,street,city,state,pin,rollnumber,courses);
                    if(flag){
                        hm.put(rollnumber, stud );
                    }
                }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                    System.out.println("Error!!! Provide numeric value..");
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Set set = hm.entrySet();
                Iterator itr = set.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry<Integer, Student> m =(Map.Entry<Integer, Student>) itr.next();
                    System.out.println(m.getValue());
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                out.writeObject(hm);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error!!! provide valid option(1-5).");
                continue;
        }

        if(option>=5)
            break;

        }while(true);
    }
}
```

hm.readObject() in StudentRunner.java, is where i am reading the content. But it clears the already written content and throws EOFException.

Comment: This may not be your problem, but don't ever try to open the same file multiple times at once; results are unpredictable at best. Instead, open the file right before you need it, read or write, and then close.

Comment: YES.. Problem was not in reading the file. May be it was because i had opened the same file for reading and writing at the same time. Problem vanished when i first read the file and then closed the handler. And opened the the file for writing wherever i needed and closed the handler after writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember always to call the `close` method on the `OutputStream` you are using to write.  The accepted idiom to do so is to do it inside a finally {} block so you make totally sure you are closing the `OutputStream` (and thus actually flushing the buffer into disk)

Comment: In Java 7+, the recommended approach is to use try(<resource def>) { }, where <resource def> is a variable definition involving opening a resource, such as creating an I/O stream. Then you don't have to use finally { } with the explicit resource closing. In addition, close() in finally { } may throw an IOException, which in turn may hide the original exception from the try { } block, if it was thrown. Note also that in case of an output stream, close() flushes the stream, which may cause an additional write operation, so that you cannot simply ignore the exception.